# Difference between lat long and coordinate format

Tags: javascript, coordinates, openlayers

I don't understand the difference between the **latitude longitude** and the "**coordinate**" format of OpenLayers.

In the OpenLayers API you have a [toLonLat](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.toLonLat)(...) method that takes a **coordinate** in parameter and returns a **latitude longitude**. I don't get how thoses two objects are different.

There is also a [tranform](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transform)() method that takes a **coordinate** and a projection and returns a **coordinate**.

I understand the use of the transform() method but don't see how its different from toLonLat() !

All thoses methods return a "[**coordinate**](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#~Coordinate)"...

Thx

Comment: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v5.2.0/src/ol/proj.js#L379

Comment: @RolandStarke Hum. So they are forcing the projection to 4326... Ok. But projection apart what is a difference between what we call a coordinate and lat long ? Is lat long a standard coordinate which has the projection 4326 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coordinate represents position in a 2D projection. While we commonly correlate "coordinate" with "degrees latitude/longitude", the units of a coordinate vary by map projection.

In the [EPSG:4326 projection](https://epsg.io/4326), coordinates are represented in degrees as `[lon, lat]`. Another common projection is [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator), or [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857), which represents coordinates in meters as `[x, y]`.

OpenLayers uses EPSG:3857 as the default map projection, so data is internally represented with coordinates in meters. It provides a convenience method (`toLonLat`) for converting those coordinates to EPSG:4326 (degrees). This is most commonly used when displaying coordinates to users, who might expect to see them represented in degrees.

Comment: ok ! I understand now ! I suspected that lat long was 4326. Thx

Answer (score 1):

A coordinate represent a location on earth, according to a specified projection. For instance, it is common to use the projection EPSG 3857 in web maps to represents the earth flat. Coordinates are then expressed in meters from a central point.

Lat-Longs are coordinates, with a real world coordinate system, i.e. it use a round(ish) earth. It is common to use coordinate system 4326, but it is not the only one.

so, lat-longs are coordinates, but not all coordinates are in lat-long

You can read this [blog](http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/4326-vs-3857) explaining the difference with graphics

Comment: thx for you answer. Am I right when I say that lat long is EPSG:4326 ?

Comment: @Doctor quiet often, but not necessarily. There are various reference elipsoid that can be used, such as [NAD83](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83/)

Comment: Ok, I see ! Thx